# How do I change the application associated with a file type but keep its icon

Tags: windows-vista, icons, file-association, file-types

Hi I want to change the default application for some file extensions but doing so also changes the icons (and file type information). Is there any way to do this without also changing its icon?

Alternatively, I can change the application and then change only the icon back afterwards. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changing the default application for a specific file type, you can change its icon from `Folder Options > File Types` window. Select the file type, click on `Advanced`. Now in Edit File Type window, click on `Change Icon`. Now you can select whatever the icon you would like to use for that file type.

**EDIT:** The questioner is looking for a solution for Vista. Hence, the following article may be helpful: [Change file extension associations and file types in Vista and Windows 7](http://4sysops.com/archives/change-file-extension-associations-and-file-types-in-vista-and-windows-7/). This is the link to the program in the article: [ASHociation](http://cleanreg3.com/fa/fashots.html).

[image]

Comment: This would help me if I were using Windows XP. But I'm not, hence the windows-vista tag. :-)

Comment: Great! I was hoping to be able to do this without resorting to 3rd party apps, but it seems that it is impossible (without mucking about in the registry myself).

Answer (score 2):

Use [File Type Manager](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) from NirSoft. You can find the example [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12383/change-a-file-types-icon-in-windows-7/)